# How to end while loop to get greatest common factor

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
a = 8
b = 6
gcf = 999
while a % gcf != 0 and b % gcf != 0:
    gcf -= 1
print(gcf)
```

I'm trying to get the greatest common factor of two numbers. I got 8 and 6 as an example. When I run the code, it gives 8 instead of 2 that I'm expecting. I though since I have `and` in the while loop it would end the loop by giving me the result that satisfy both statements.

Comment: When `gcf` reaches 8, your first test is `8 % 8 != 0`, which is false. Why aren't you just using [the Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)?

Comment: I don't think you want mod operator here... At least not the way you're using it. Because having gcf greater than either number will always result in 0

Answer (score 0):

## Your implementation

Regarding your implementation you want to loop until both modulo operation are zero, this means looping as long as one `or` the other is non-zero. Also note that the *gcf* cannot be greater than the minimum of both numbers.

```
a = 8
b = 6
gcf = min(a, b)  # This is the max value your gcf can take

while a % gcf or b % gcf:  # Use 'or' in your condition
    gcf -= 1

print(gcf) # 2
```

## The builtin `math.gcd`

Although, for big enough numbers you want to use a more efficient implementation that uses the [Euclidian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Procedure), that is what `math.gcd` does. Note that `gcd` stands for *greatest common divisor* which is the mathematical name of the number you are looking for.

```
import math

math.gcd(8, 6) # 2
```

Comment: Shouldn't the initialization be: gcf = min(a, b)? The common factor can't possibly be larger than the smallest one of a and b.

Answer (score 0):

First, to make the search for the `gcf` faster, you should start at the minimum of `a` and `b`, since the `gcf` is not going to be greater than any of them. Also, you need to replace `and` with `or` because you want to keep changing `gcf` until it divides both `a` and `b`, so you loop while it doesn't divide one of them.

Your code then would be:

```
a = 8
b = 6
gcf = min(a, b)  # minimum of a and b
while a % gcf != 0 or b % gcf != 0:  # OR instead of AND
    gcf -= 1
print(gcf)  # => 2
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation really cleared up my confusion